# How to avoid nested ternary in render?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, if-statement

This is my case:

```
<Form onSubmit={submit}>
                    {something === 0 ?
                        (someData.length && someData.length > 0) ?
                            doSomething() : null :
                        (someOtherData.length && someOtherData.length > 0) ?
                            doSomethingElse() : null
                    }
</Form>
```

However, eslint rule is giving me error: `Do not nest ternary expressions`.

How can this be avoided?
Can if - else be written in `return (...)` which renders data?

Comment: Duplicate of [if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046037/if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs) or [how-to-do-a-nested-if-else-statement-in-reactjs-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312122/how-to-do-a-nested-if-else-statement-in-reactjs-jsx)

Comment: If your logic gets increasingly complex, you could always just move it outside the render into a function and call the function in the render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you do the validations before the return of the render method

```
render () {
  myComponent = <></>;

  if (something === 0) {
      if (someData.length && someData.length > 0) {
        myComponent = doSomething();
      }
  } else if (someOtherData.length && someOtherData.length > 0) {
      myComponent = doSomethingElse();
  }

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={submit}>
      {<myComponent/>}
    </Form>
  )
}
```

If you want the validations within the component you could try it this way

```
<Form onSubmit={submit}>
    {
      something === 0 && someData.length && someData.length > 0
        ? doSomething()
        : something !== 0 && someOtherData.length && someOtherData.length > 0 && doSomethingElse()
    }
</Form>
```

Comment: @storagemode11
try it
`{
      something === 0 && someData.length && someData.length > 0
        ? doSomething()
        : something !== 0 && someOtherData.length && someOtherData.length > 0 && doSomethingElse()
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate the behaviour into a function on the component

```
renderComponent() {
  return something ?
    someOtherData.length && doSomethingElse() :
    someData.length && doSomething();
}

render() {
  ...
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={submit}>
      {renderComponent()}
    </Form>
  );
}
```

*Tip - you don't need to explicitly pass `null`, React supports [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)*