# Do not nest ternary expressions - Way to change between 3 styles based on coditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to display 3 different styles based on coditions but I cant do it using ternary expression. I've found some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312122/how-to-do-a-nested-if-else-statement-in-reactjs-jsx) but still having some trouble with it.
The following conditions are the one I wanted to do:

```js
<div className={styles.extraContainer}>
      {
         (() => {
                if (!opened && !followed )
                    <div id={styles.themeBox}><p>+10</p></div>  //show this box
                else if (opened && !followed)
                   <img src={arrowDownIcon} alt="" style={{height:'1.2em', 
                   marginLRight:'10px', width:'auto', objectFit:'contain'}} />   //show this icon
                else  
                   ""     //show nothing
          })()
      }
</div>
```

Cause when I tried the following code, I received **Do not nest ternary expressions.** error.

```js
{!opened && !followed ? <div id={styles.themeBox}><p>+10</p></div> : (opened && !followed ? <img src={arrowDownIcon} alt="" style={{height:'1.2em', marginLRight:'10px', width:'auto', objectFit:'contain'}} /> : ""}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that best readable solution is this:

```
<div className={styles.extraContainer}>
      {!opened && !followed &&
        <div id={styles.themeBox}><p>+10</p></div>  //show this box
      }
      {opened && !followed &&
       <img src={arrowDownIcon} alt="" style={{height:'1.2em', 
                   marginLRight:'10px', width:'auto', objectFit:'contain'}} />  //show this icon
      }
</div>
```

Or you can nest the conditions:

```
<div className={styles.extraContainer}>
      {!followed && <>
       {!opened &&
        <div id={styles.themeBox}><p>+10</p></div>  //show this box
       }
       {opened && 
        <img src={arrowDownIcon} alt="" style={{height:'1.2em', 
                   marginLRight:'10px', width:'auto', objectFit:'contain'}} />  //show this icon
       }
   </>}
</div>
```

Comment: The first solution solved my problem, thank you! But not the second solution which is to nest the conditions, what does `<>` and `</>` means in that?

Comment: <> </> is short syntax for <React.Fragment></React.Fragment> :)